# Analog for 'side', but for front vs. rear

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms, analogy

I wish to name a property that expresses whether something is in the front or at the rear.  This term has to be used together with 'side' without causing ambiguity.

Much like 'side' can be left or right, 'height' can be high or low, '????' can be front or rear.

Is there a word for that?

Comment: Location? Where?

Comment: @medica: thanks, but Location/Where would be too vague.  I edited the question to indicate that.

Comment: *Front* and *back,* surely?

Comment: Why the downvote, I wonder? This is a really good question… to which I can't think of an answer. The same goes for top/bottom, though.

Comment: I seriously doubt if there's a convenient term for this. Else why would the pundits use *anterioposterior* ( *anteriority-posteriority* ) instead?

Comment: Front-end, back-end, front-face, back-face? Note that the difference between location terms for *side* and *face* arises naturally: humans, and many other things, are *bilaterally* symmetric. So the *sides* look and can be treated similarly. But not the *faces*; humans have only one *face* and it *faces* forward. None the less, our butts (*rear **end***) *face* backwards.